# Dimension of closure of set of closed points in a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral scheme. Let $Z\subset X$ be a set of closed points in $X$.

What is the dimension of the closure of $Z$?

Comment: In general $Z$ is not open in $\overline{Z}$ (think about schemes of finite type over a field).

Comment: Ow I was confuse there. You're right. I could consider the set of closed points $Z$ in a curve. Its closure is the whole set. Moreover, $Z$ is not open in the curve, because the generic point is not closed.

Comment: You mean the dimension of the closure compared to $\dim Z$ ?